# Sitecore 6.5 DMS - Registering a goal completion via the API

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I want to register a goal/conversion on my Sitecore 6.5 site using the API rather than a 'thank-you' page.

I've seen this question about how to do it [Sitecore OMS - achieving a goal on a form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019635/sitecore-oms-achieving-a-goal-on-a-form-submission) but the answer relates to the API prior to Sitecore 6.5 where it was overhauled quite significantly.

Has anyone done this? Or has this functionality been intentionally removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage != null)
    {
        PageEventData eventData = new PageEventData("My Goal Name");
        eventData.Data = "this is some event data.";
        VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow pageEventsRow = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(eventData);
        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Submit();
    }
}
```

That should register the goal on the currentpage, but not before you decide to in your code

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks this is a great start! The argument to this method is a `PageEventData` object which you initialise with a name (`new PageEventData("Contact us form Completed")`) do I need to populate the other properties of this object before passing it to `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(...)` ?

Comment: It depends. The PageEventData is custom data you can add to your event. For instance if you want to add fields entered in a form. Otherwise you should be fine with just registering the goal.

Comment: I've tried the code I mentioned in my comment and am still not seeing the record appear in the database.  Is there something I'm missing? I've updated the question to include details of the code I am using.

Comment: Hmmm have you tried public VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow Register(string name, string text); To see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a modified version of the code which references the Goal Item by its GUID:

```
if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage != null)
{
PageEventItem goal = new PageEventItem(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("GOALGUID"));
VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow pageEventsRow = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(goal);
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Submit();
}
```

Make sure you have deployed and published your goal and or goal category too as the code will fail otherwise.