# Programatically track a visit to an item with a profile card

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

We've just taken over a site that a client is wanting to add personalisation to using profile and pattern cards.

However the way the sites been built means that a visitor never actually goes to the url for the item that would have the profile card assigned to it. Instead there going to a single page and a value on the query string tells the page which items data should be loaded. Therefore the user is never tracked as visiting the item and the profile card has no influence on the profile for the user.

Is there a way to pragmatically trigger what would normally happen so that the users builds up the profile score for these pages?

The site is using Sitecore 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the analytics dll I found that you can do this.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
(new TrackingFieldProcessor()).Process(db.GetItem(new ID("395BDEF7-16CB-4C94-B9B6-A6EAC148401F")));
```

This will cause the profile key values to be updated correctly, but the visitor histroy will still look like the visitor didn't look at the page. To change that you can do this.

```
VisitorDataSet.PagesRow rawUrl = Tracker.CurrentVisit.GetOrCreateCurrentPage();
rawUrl.Url = "new url value";
rawUrl.UrlText = "new url value";
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to programmatically trigger a profile using the Analytics api.

```csharp
 var profile = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit.GetOrCreateProfile("<Profile Name>");
 profile.BeginEdit();
 profile.Score("<profile key>",<profile key value you want to set>);
 profile.Score("<profile key>",<profile key value you want to set>);
 profile.UpdatePattern(); //sets the appropriate pattern based on the       current profile keys values you have just set.
 profile.EndEdit();
```

I would also take a look at the other methods on the Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit object to perform other operations

Comment: That would replace the current scores for each key with the value entered rather than adding the item's view to the users history and the score being updated in the normal way using the combination of all page views wouldn't it?

Comment: why do you have the line "profile.Score("<profile key>",<profile key value you want to set>);" twice

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to register page events? If so, you may want to try programmatically creating page event items and registering them.

Example:

```
PageEventItem pei = new PageEventItem(goalItem);
VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow pageEventsRow = Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(pei);
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Submit();
```

The above code assumes you have programmatically retrieved the Sitecore item for a goal (goalItem). It then registers the page event and submits the change. You could do the same thing with events or campaigns.

Other resources:

- [Sitecore 6.5 DMS - Registering a goal completion via the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976407/sitecore-6-5-dms-registering-a-goal-completion-via-the-api)
- [How do I trigger a profile in Sitecore DMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881011/how-do-i-trigger-a-profile-in-sitecore-dms)
- https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/damian-brooks/posts/2014/08/06082014.aspx
- http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2013/11/19/sitecore-dms-trigger-goals-programatically/
- http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2013/07/Sitecore-DMS-Register-Goal.aspx

Comment: I tried registering a page view event on the item containing the data (which also has the profile card assigned), but that didn't seem to have any effect on the current scoring for the users profile. Just added a page event record.